# Find the number(s) $k$ such that $k\mathbb{Z} = \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, integers

I am just starting out with Discrete Math and there is a question in my book that is

> Find the number(s) $k$ such that $k \mathbb{Z} = \mathbb{Z}$.

The answer is -1 and 1. I understand why it is 1 because any number multiplied by 1 is itself, what I don't understand is why the other answer is -1.

For example, if $k = -1$ then  $(-1)\mathbb{Z}$ would be all the values of $\mathbb{Z}$, but if that is the case, then why can't $k$ could also equal 2 or any other integer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yanko resolved it already, but I'll flesh it out a bit more as you seemed sure that $(-1)\mathbb{Z} = \mathbb{Z}$ but unsure whether, for example, $2\mathbb{Z} \ne \mathbb{Z}$. This makes me think that $k\mathbb{Z}$ is slightly confusing to you.

So by $k\mathbb{Z}$ we just mean the set of all integers multiplied by $k$ (or equivalently, the set of all multiples of $k$):

$$k\mathbb{Z} = \{ kn \mid n \in \mathbb{Z} \} = \{\dots,-2k,-k,0,k,2k,\dots\}$$

Thus,

$$1\mathbb{Z} = \{ 1n \mid n \in \mathbb{Z} \} = \{\dots,-2,-1,0,1,2,\dots\} = \mathbb{Z} \tag 1$$

$$(-1)\mathbb{Z} = \{ (-1)n \mid n \in \mathbb{Z} \} = \{\dots,2,1,0,-1,-2,\dots\} = \mathbb{Z} \tag 2$$

$$2\mathbb{Z} = \{ 2n \mid n \in \mathbb{Z} \} = \{\dots,-4,-2,0,2,4,\dots\} \ne \mathbb{Z}$$

Also, remember that with sets, order doesn't matter, which is why $(1)$ and $(2)$ are true.

I hope this makes it a bit clearer.

Comment: Is $2\mathbb{Z}$ is invalid because numbers get skipped in the set that exist in $\mathbb{Z}$? If that is the case then is $7\mathbb{Q}= \mathbb{Q}$ valid?

Comment: Yes, $2\mathbb{Z}$ is just the even integers, meaning that it doesn't contain any odd integers! For the second question, what do you think? Have you tried enumerating some example elements yet?

Comment: Any rational number multiplied by 7 still returns a rational number, but I am not sure if skips any numbers as with $2\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Right, so $7\mathbb{Q} \subseteq \mathbb{Q}$. Is it possible to prove the other direction, that is, $\mathbb{Q} \subseteq 7\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: In this case, it would help to define precisely what a rational number is.

Comment: To help a little bit more, can you prove formally that $(-1)\mathbb{Z} = \mathbb{Z}$ by showing that they are subsets of each other? I think you came to conclusion of $(-1)\mathbb{Z} = \mathbb{Z}$ by having an intuitive feel for what each set look like, but proving it formally (i.e., showing that each set is a subset of the other) will help you more in the long run, especially with this problem concerning the rationals.

Answer (score 0):

If $k\mathbb{Z} = \mathbb{Z}$ then $1\in k\mathbb{Z}$ (in fact this is an if and only if) but then $\frac{1}{k}\in\mathbb{Z}$. This means that $k\in\{-1,1\}$.